# Iterate over dataframe for a value in multiple columns and print something for each row returned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the example dataframe below,

How do I iterate over both Grade 1 and Grade 2 columns to select any grade 1 greater than 24 with any Grade 2 greater than 50 using list_comprehension or vectorization mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/12928378)

```python
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Name':['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'], 
        'Grade 1':[27, 24, 22, 32], 
        'Grade 2':[60, 50, 75, 60],
        'Final Grade':[77, 74, 97, 92]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df[['Name', 'Grade 1', 'Grade 2','Final Grade']])
```

Based on those conditions I would like the expected output to return something like:

```
Jai has Grade 1 score of 27 and Grade 2 score of 60
Anuj has Grade 1 score of 32 and Grade 2 score 60
Gaurav has Grade 1 score of 22 and Grade 2 score of 75
```

Following a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dealing-with-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/) but trying to go beyond in understanding how to implement either of those concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear so I hope you can clarify things a bit. For example, you need Grade 1 which are greater than 24 but in your expected output, you are expecting Gaurav with 22.

However, to make things simpler, I would say never try to iterate in pandas. At the very least, it is a practice that is best left for exception cases.

Here you can use conditional assignments :

```
df[(df['Grade 1'] > 24) & (df['Grade 2'] > 50 )]]

out :
 Name     Grade 1    Grade 2    Final Grade 
 Jai        27         60           77
Anuj        32         60           92
```

Edit : If in case you wish to have an output with either Grade 1 > 24 **OR** Grade 2 > 50, just replace & with '|'

Comment: yep that was exactly what I needed to have Gaurav show too ! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
res = df[(df['Grade 1'] > 24) & (df['Grade 2'] > 50)]
print(res)

   Name  Grade 1  Grade 2  Final Grade
0   Jai       27       60           77
3  Anuj       32       60           92
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`, although, in this case, I do not think it will make too much difference.

```py
df[(df["Grade 1"] > 24) & (df["Grade 2"] > 50)].apply(
    lambda x: f"{x['Name']} has Grade 1 score of {x['Grade 1']} and Grade 2 score of {x['Grade 2']}",
    axis=1,
).tolist()


['Jai has Grade 1 score of 27 and Grade 2 score of 60',
 'Anuj has Grade 1 score of 32 and Grade 2 score of 60']
```

Comment: this also helped & I changed the & to | which included Gaurav